# User Management in Multi tenancy with Asp.net boilerplate .NET Core

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I created a multitenant application with Abp framework (.NET core 3.1), I noticed that each tenant in the application has isolated user management and isolated roles management.
But in my case, I wanna one User Management for all tenants so if I create User1 in **Default Tenant**,I wanna log in by it for **Tenant2**.

Does that scenario applicable in Abp .NET core?

Answer (score 0):

I guess good to think about a single database approach with shared entity across tenants

see the link [https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy#determining-current-tenant][1]